# ArgumentError: comparison of Hash with Hash failed - Sorting an array of hashes by hash name

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have the following array:

```
names = [
{"Adriana"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
{"Adriane"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
{"Agatha"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
{"Adrianna"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}}
]
```

How would I sort this array of hashes by the name of each hash?

I have tried: `names.sort!`, which throws `ArgumentError: comparison of Hash with Hash failed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do as below using [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) method.

```
names = [
{"Adriana"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
{"Adriane"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
{"Agatha"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
{"Adrianna"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}}
]

names.sort_by { |h| h.first.first }
# => [{"Adriana"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
#     {"Adriane"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
#     {"Adrianna"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}},
#     {"Agatha"=>{:gender=>"female", :nationality=>"danish"}}]
```

Comment: Just tried using Ruby 1.9.3 and this worked just fine.